# Assertion failure Error in OS X app when seguing/opening a new window

Tags: swift, macos

I am getting this error in the console of my OS X app anytime I try to open a new window.

`Assertion failure in -[NSNibExternalObjectPlaceholder initWithCoder:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1561.20.106/AppKit.subproj/Storyboarding/NSNibExternalObjectPlaceholder.m:75
2018-03-02 19:50:14.647897-0500 Main Algo[35239:895896] [General] Missing placeholder for identifier 'UpstreamPlaceholder-cSW-Mj-Qck'`

I have no idea what it means and there is a stack trace below it.

I have a show segue to a new window and when I click on a button to trigger that segue, this shows up in the console but the app doesn't crash or anything. I just am not able to open any new windows and every time I try to this message is added to the console.

It does not happen all the time. The app has to be running for a little while and after a while, I am no able to open any other windows and I get this error. If I restart the app, everything is fine.

The app name is `Main Algo`